# Is there a way to set Quirks Mode by default in IE10 running 64bit

Tags: configuration, 64-bit, default, internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode

I was wondering if there is a way that my IE10 browser would be set to Quirks Mode automatically when I open it? I'm using a windows 8 64-bit. I am accessing a site that needs to be in Quirks Mode and when I open my browser I still need to change it to quirks mode to be able to access the site properly. And when I restart my computer and open the browser again I have to set it again to quirks mode. And this is really tiring.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you willing to write a userscript? If not, I'm afraid this isn't programming related.

Comment: what would be the script? do I have to write the script every time I open my browser?

Answer (score 0):

Specification of an IE rendering mode also applies to IE5 Quirks Mode. To run instances of a WebBrowser control in IE5 Quirks Mode, insert the following value into the registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_NATIVE_DOCUMENT_MODE]

"iexplore.exe"=dword:C350 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]

"iexplore.exe"=dword:C350
```

**References**

- [Understanding Compatibility Modes in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx)
- [Obsolete Feature Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330738)